# Remove an external handler/library on a input box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is is possible to remove an externally applied library to and element using jquery.
I have an `input` and I change the class of the box based on a click condition. IF the input has class email, I need to attach a `.mailgun_validator()` to it whereas if the class is text, I need to unbind it. Below is my code snippet:

```
$('.selection-input-box').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
          // Insert the mailgun validator
            $(this).mailgun_validator({
                api_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                success: validation_success,
                error: validation_error
            });
        } else {
          // Remove the handler. Unbind doesn't work here
            $(this).unbind('mailgun_validator');
        }
    });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does `this` have any other custom events assigned to it? If no, you could simply clone it and replace it - `$(this).replaceWith($(this).clone())`

Comment: @eithedog The input box class value changes on selection of radio buttons. The condition is set in that way. Apart from that there are no custom events assigned to it except the validation.

Answer (score 0):

mailgun_validator plugin itself has no method to remove it. I have seen in the [code](https://github.com/mailgun/validator-demo/blob/master/mailgun_validator.js) that it uses focusout event. You may unregister all focusout events on the element:

```
$(this).off('focusout');
```